# Passing Argument 1 makes integer from pointer without a cast warning for putchar

Tags: c, warnings

I'm studying an exercise of making a simple code that has the function that acts the same way as printf using a **variadic function**.

Also, I wish to use sprintf and putchar, and not printf.

The code seems to act and give the results as it should do (i.e print a character for %c, and an integer for %d).

However, I keep getting **a warning message** for `putchar(cStr);` that says `Passing Argument 1 of 'putchar' makes integer from pointer without a cast`.

Also, I get a **note** that says `expected int but argument is of type char *`.

I've tried to get this solved by changing `putchar(cStr);` into `putchar(*cStr);`, but then the code gives me a `segment fault`.

**What should I do to get the warning message and note solved?**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

void new_printf(const char*format, ...);

int main(void)
{
    new_printf("A single character : %c An integer : %d \n", 'T', 37);
    return 0;
}

void new_printf(const char *format, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    char ary[50];
    char *cStr;
    int iNum, i=0;
    va_start(ap, format);
    while(*format)
    { 
        if(strncmp(format, "%d",2) == 0){
            iNum = va_arg(ap, int);
            sprintf(ary, "%d", iNum);
            while(ary[i]!='\0'){
                putchar(ary[i]);
                i++;
            }       
            format = format + 2;
        }
        else if(strncmp(format, "%c", 2)==0)
        {
            cStr = va_arg(ap, char*);
            putchar(cStr);
            format = format + 2;
        }
        else{
            putchar(*format);
            format++;
        }
    }
    va_end(ap);
}
```

The correct results would be as follows:

```
A single character : T An integer : 37
```

Comment: `putchar` takes only `char` not `char *`

Comment: @irAM but the results come out fine? and also, if I change the ```va_arg(ap, char*);``` to ```va_arg(ap, char);``` it doesn't really solve anything...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the call `new_printf("A single character : %c An integer : %d \n", 'T', 37);`, `'T'` is passed for the `%c` conversion. `'T'` is a character: It is a small integer value. It is not a pointer. For historic reasons, its type is `int`. This is a correct thing to pass for `%c`.

Under `else if(strncmp(format, "%c", 2)==0)`, in `cStr = va_arg(ap, char*);`, you tell `va_arg` to give you the next argument and that that argument is a `char *`. It is not. It is an `int`.

You should retrieve it with `va_arg` as an `int` and assign it to an `int`, not to `char *`, or simply use it directly as an `int`.

You should use `int x = va_arg(ap, int); putchar(x);` or simply `putchar(va_arg(ap, int));`.

Comment: But is there any way of maintaining the ```char*``` instead of changing it to an ```int```? because in the method of getting a ```%s```, it seems possible to use a ```char*```, such as ```cStr = va_arg(ap, char*); while(*cStr){ putchar(*cStr++);}```? How is this different from ```%c``` using ```int```?

Comment: @Learner_15: If the caller passes an `int`, you must take it as an `int` with `va_arg`. But you are writing a new routine. If you want to specify that, with your routine, the caller must pass a `char *` for `%c`, then you can do that. Then the caller must pass a `char *`, and you must take it as a `char *` with `va_arg`. Then your routine will behave differently from `printf`.

Comment: So it would be possible then to take a ```char*```? I'm sorry but this is the part that I was aiming to make.. would it be too much if I asked you how to write by this routine of the caller passing a ```char*``` for ```%c```?